# React source code no longer showing in DevTools after upgrading to Chrome 87

Tags: reactjs

I upgraded my Chrome to version 87. I no longer am seeing my React source code in DevTools. The React Chrome Extension is installed and permission to access local files is enabled. So what could be the problem?

Comment: did you try to close and reponed chrome? worked for me

Comment: Yes and even restarted my machine.

Comment: well am on chrome Version 87.0.4280.88  and I do see the react extension so it's not a chrome issue, maybe reinstall the extension?

Comment: Yeah I reinstalled but that didn't help either.